# how to programmatically add colspan in ZK/Zul?

Tags: zk, zul

How to set property of colspan in ZUL framework?

e.g.

```
Tr tr = new Tr();

Td td = new Td();

tr.appendChild(td);


td = new Td();

tr.appendChild(td);
```

now, in next row, i have to put up single td inside the table row through composer which will cover the space of two td . how can i achieve this?

```
<Table>
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td/>
       <td>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please update your question ? do you need <Table><tr><td/><td/><td/></tr><tr><td/></tr></table>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ZUL this is not done with `<table>`, `<tr>`, and `<td>` tags but with `<grid>`, `<row>`, and `<cell>` tags. Like so..

```
<grid>
    <columns>
        <column label="A" />
        <column label="B" />
    </columns>
    <rows>
        <row>
            <cell>
                <label value="item 1" />
            </cell>
            <cell>
                <label value="item 2" />
            </cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell colspan="2">
                <label value="item 3" />
            </cell>
        </row>
    </rows>
</grid>
```

From the Java side, then, this becomes easy..

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
Rows rows = new Rows();
rows.setParent(grid);
Row row1 = new Row();
row1.setParent(rows);
Cell cell1 = new Cell();
cell1.setParent(row1);
cell1.appendChild(new Label("item1"));
Cell cell2 = new Cell();
cell2.setParent(row1);
cell2.appendChild(new Label("item2"));
Row row2 = new Row();
row2.setParent(rows);
Cell cell3 = new Cell();
cell3.setParent(row2);
cell3.appendChild(new Label("item3"));
cell3.setColspan(2); // this is what you're looking for
```

Please refer to the (great) [ZK docs](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Supplementary/Cell) for more information.